# Dates Expiring By Custom Field date_modify

Tags: datetime, expiration

Can I somehow set the expiration date of an entry based on a custom-field. I ask this because I don't want the site-owner to have to manually set the expiration date (for multiple reasons)but they are setting a 'start' date in a custom field. I am currently outputting entries and limiting them by doing this:

```
{% for event in entries %}
                    {% set count = 0 %}
                    {% if count < 5 and event.dateTime|date_modify('tomorrow 5am')|date('U') > now|date('U') %}
```

It would be really fantastic though if i was able to use that same date_modify to expire the entry and remove the entries from the loop all-together due to being expired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a fairly simple plugin to automatically set the expiration based off of another field value or calculation.

In your plugin's main file:

```
public function init() {

    parent::init();

    craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', function(Event $event) {

        $entry = $event->params['entry'];

        if ($entry->section == 'Events') {

            if (empty($entry->expiryDate)) {
                $date = new DateTime($entry->dateTime);
                $modifiedDate = date_modify($date, 'tomorrow 5am');
                $entry->expiryDate = $modifiedDate;
                craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
            }

        }

    });

}
```

**Updated Code** fixed syntax errors and added a check to see if expiration date is already set, otherwise created an endless loop (and may overwrite a manual setting).

Comment: You're on fire today, Douglas... I can't keep up.